# unable to load static css file in the dash app

Tags: python, css, django, pycharm, plotly-dash

I have built a single page dash app which runs as expected when run as a single file, but when I am trying to run it as a whole app, the CSS does not load correctly.

Below is my folder structure

[image]

While I load the whole app by `manage.py` below is the error that I get

```
Internal Server Error: /assets/internal.css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\my_project\analyser_tool\views.py", line 32, in dash_index
    return HttpResponse(dispatcher(request))
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\my_project\analyser_tool\views.py", line 27, in dispatcher
    return response.get_data()
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 986, in get_data
    self._ensure_sequence()
  File "C:\Users\Tushar\Documents\serato_video_analyser\video_analyser\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\wrappers.py", line 1035, in _ensure_sequence
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted implicit sequence conversion '
RuntimeError: Attempted implicit sequence conversion but the response object is in direct passthrough mode.
```

This is my only second dash app that I am working and unfortunately does not have much experience in it. I am really hopping if some could please help me fix this issue. I have been struggling with it for couple of days now.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With continued research, I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following to my server.py

```
css_directory = os.getcwd()
stylesheets = ['stylesheet.css']
static_css_route = '/static/'


@app.server.route('{}<stylesheet>'.format(static_css_route))
def serve_stylesheet(stylesheet):
    if stylesheet not in stylesheets:
        raise Exception(
            '"{}" is excluded from the allowed static files'.format(
                stylesheet
            )
        )
    return flask.send_from_directory(css_directory, stylesheet)


for stylesheet in stylesheets:
    app.css.append_css({"external_url": "/static/{}".format(stylesheet)})
```

This answer was answered before and is taken from

https://community.plot.ly/t/serve-locally-option-with-additional-scripts-and-style-sheets/6974/6